# Why doesn't a socket send the last message unless there is a delay before it?

Tags: java, android, sockets

Alright so I am looking at this piece of code that is supposed to get an array of bytes which represents an image and send it piece by piece to a server. The server needs to be told when the image transmission is done, this ending message is "CLOSE". Everything works fine but unless I uncomment Thread.sleep the end message isn't sent. Also the delay needs to be quite big for some reason, 100 ms for example doesn't work. If anyone could provide an explanation for this behaviour I would be grateful since I don't have a very good understanding of java.

```
private class NetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    private String ip;
    private byte[] to_send;

    public NetTask(String ip, byte[] to_send)
    {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.to_send = to_send;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params)
    {
        try {
            Log.i(dTag, "" + to_send.length);
            Socket sck = new Socket(ip, 1234);
            DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(sck.getOutputStream());
            dOut.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(to_send.length).array());
            Log.d(dTag, "" + to_send.length);
            int x = 500;
            int len = to_send.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < len - x + 1; i += x)
                dOut.write(Arrays.copyOfRange(to_send, i, i + x));

            if (len % x != 0)
                dOut.write(Arrays.copyOfRange(to_send, len - len % x, len));
            /*try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.d(dTag, "thread sleep error");
            }*/
            dOut.write("CLOSE".getBytes());
            dOut.flush();
            dOut.close();
            sck.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.d(dTag, ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The server is in c#, here is the code:

```
while (ok)
{
    sck.Listen(1000);
    Socket accepted = sck.Accept();
    buffer = new byte[accepted.SendBufferSize];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    bool reading = true;
    int im_size = -1;
    int index = 0;
    byte[] image = null;
    while (reading)
    {
        bytesRead = accepted.Receive(buffer);
        if (bytesRead == 5)
            Console.WriteLine(bytesRead);
        string strData = "YADA";
        byte[] formatted = new byte[bytesRead];
        if (bytesRead == 5)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
            {
                formatted[i] = buffer[i];
            }
            strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
        }
        if (strData == "CLOSE")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GOT CLOSE MESSAGE");
            Image im = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(image));
            im.Save(@"D:\im1.bmp");
        }
        else
        {
            if (im_size == -1)
            {
                im_size = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
                image = new byte[im_size];
                Console.WriteLine(im_size);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead && index < im_size; i++)
                {
                    image[index++] = buffer[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    accepted.Close();
}
```

Comment: That's strange. Do you also have the server code that is reading the socket?

Comment: there's an evil magic option -- `TCP_NODELAY` :) maybe related.

Comment: @Markus The server code is in c# but i'm posting it in a minute.

Comment: you should try @bayou.io 's suggestion

Comment: Tried the TCP_NODELAY, it works like a charm, I have no idea why but it does, thank you!